# Docker login to gcp using json credentials

Tags: windows, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I want to log into docker on google cloud from the command line in **Windows** using credentials in json format.

Firstly, I generated the keys of the service accounts in google cloud IAM & Admin. Afterwards, I tried to login [as advised](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json_key_file) using the following commands:

```
set /p PASS=<keyfile.json
docker login -u _json_key -p "%PASS%" https://[HOSTNAME]
```

The json that is generated from google, though, has *newline* characters and the 
above *set* command couldn't read the whole file. 
Then, I edited the file to be a single line. But still, the set command is not reading the whole file. Any advice on how to read a json file using the *set* command and pass it to the docker login command below?

Comment: The set command results in the last line of input. Compare `echo %PASS%` with the actual file. I recommend using the Access Token method as the token will fit into an environment variable: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#access_token

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution on this is to run the following command:

```
docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io < keyfile.json
```

Comment: What if I wish to generate `~/.docker/config.json`?

Comment: ... but this shares the private key in the json file over the network.. :|